# How to override theme defaults for Minimal Mistakes theme

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a website hosted on GitHub pages using the [Minimal Mistakes](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/) Jekyll theme. I am working on some basic customization - still trying to learn - so am starting out by practicing with some simple theme changes. I am starting out by reading through the [Stylesheet](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/stylesheets/) portion of the documentation.

Here, I decided to start out with one of the first examples listed on this page, by trying to override the theme default for the `link-color`. Here I am having a bit of trouble however.

I started out by following the recommendations outline on this page. I made sure to navigate to the `main.scss` file in my website's repo and then add the line `link-color: red;` at the top of the file (making sure to add it above any of the `@import` statements). However, after adding this line, nothing seemed to change and the default link-color for the website still displayed as a light blue.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have read a few things online which have suggested similar issues and provided varying degrees of advice/solutions with varying levels of complexity. I am very new to Jekyll themes and was just trying this out as a good first intro into more complex customization.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here or have any links to helpful examples, tutorials, or resources?

Also, here is the link to the [Minimal Mistakes repo](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) on GitHub and [my forked version](https://github.com/eolesinski/eolesinski.github.io) of the repo here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me some time to find out :)

**Reason:**

You set a color and it gets always overwritten by `$info-color` because the `!default` flag is missing in https://github.com/eolesinski/eolesinski.github.io/blob/master/_sass/_variables.scss:

```
$info-color                 : #52adc8;
$link-color                 : $info-color;
```

From [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/creating-stylesheet-feature-flags-with-sass-default/#:%7E:text=default%20is%20a%20Sass%20flag,%24variable%3A%20%27test%27%20!):

> `!default` is a Sass flag that indicates conditional assignment to a variable — it assigns a value only if the variable was previously undefined or null.

**Solution:**

Add `!default` after `$info-color` inside the `$link-color` definition to be able to overwrite `$link-color` on top of the main css file. New entry: `$link-color: $info-color !default;`

Or, change the link color directly in the `_variables.scss` file.

Default colors in Visual studio code:

[image]

Overwrite and result:

[image]

**Details on how the theme works:**

Your cloned version differs from the official repository. It also does not support skins. Not sure what else is missing. You cannot follow the docs in any case. You could update it to the official version.

The original repo imports the following sass files:

```
@import "minimal-mistakes/skins/{{ site.minimal_mistakes_skin | default: 'default' }}"; // skin
@import "minimal-mistakes"; // main partials
```

This results in the following import order (skipped irrelevant imports):

1. skin
2. variable (@import "minimal-mistakes/variables";)
3. reset (@import "minimal-mistakes/reset";)

The _config.yml file defines a skin (default by default, no color set):

```
minimal_mistakes_skin: "default"
```

Other **skins** (such as skins/_air.scss) define their own link color:

```
$link-color: #393e46 !default;
```

The **variable** CSS file (_sass/minimal-mistakes/_variables.scss) defines the default link color by using the $info-color (if not overwritten manually or by the skin before):

```
$link-color: mix(#000, $info-color, 20%) !default;
```

The **reset** CSS file (_sass/minimal-mistakes/_reset.scss) defines that links should use the variable:

```
a {
  color: $link-color;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` elements on the website's homepage (`about.md`) has inline style  `style="color:#4196ce"`. Inline style is considered the highest CSS specificity and is the value that will always be used over what is found in the stylesheets.

> - Note: `!important` is an exception to this rule and can override inline style.
> - To learn more see CSS Specificity by MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

If you decide to remove the inline styles, you would have to add `$link-color: red;` **after** the line `@import "variables";` where `$link-color` is first defined. Putting your custom style before `@import "variables";` will result in `$link-color` value being taken from `_sass/_variables.scss`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get part of what you are saying here. For clarification, I am trying to change the link color default site-wide (so that all links formatted on the site are the same color). Does this mean that I would need to change the $link-color parameter in the _sass/_variables.sass directory?